# Rails, turning an image into a link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, hyperlink

I want to turn my image into a link. But how?   I read different answers but nothing worked.

```
 <%= link_to image_tag(article.images.first.image.url, :alt => article.title) unless 
      article.images.first.nil? %>
```

I used this link to refer to the article by the title.

```
<%= link_to(article) do %><h2><%= article.title %></h2><% end %>
This works!  the path.     But i want the same path "article" with the image.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe you can do this ?  do a check outside link_to

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
<%= link_to image_tag(article.images.first.image.url, :alt => article.title) unless 
  article.images.first.nil?, article %>
```